# 4 square css transitions

Tags: css, css-grid

Maybe someone can help me with this. I'm trying to create this four square layout on a website.[4 squares with close button at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDVMK.gif) I first tried using flexbox and couldnt get it to work with flex-grow, now using css grid and the animate-css-grid library. Almost got it but still has a few problems.

1. the abolute positioned images lose their spacing when it is expanded
2. the transitions are choppy and don't look pleasing.

Heres how I have it setup right now:

```
const MilestoneMainSection = styled(Section)`
    transition: 1s all ease-in;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Electro-Shackle', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(20%) fit-content(20%);
    grid-template-rows: fit-content(20%) fit-content(20%);
    grid-gap: 5vw 20vw;
`;

const BoardMainSection = styled(Section)`
    position: relative;
    padding: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    ${(props) =>
        !props.isClicked &&
        props.selected &&
        css`
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        `}
    ${(props) =>
        props.isClicked &&
        css`
            grid-column: 1 / span 2;
            grid-row: 1 / span 2;
            padding: 0%;
        `}
`;

<MilestoneMainSection selected={selected} ref={gridRef} onClick={() => selected && setSelected(null)}>
    <BoardMainSection selected={selected} isClicked={selected === 2} onClick={() => setSelected(2)}>
                    <div>
                        <Section textCentered centered width={'100%'} margin={'1rem 0'}>
                            <Text smallTitle shadowed={colors.deeppink} color={colors.deeppink}>
                                Mobile App
                            </Text>
                        </Section>
                        <Section centered>
                            <Text main color={colors.lightcyan}>
                                Coming Soon
                            </Text>
                        </Section>
                    </div>
                </BoardMainSection>
</MilestoneMainSection>
```

Desired funcitonality is to have 4 smalls squares that expand to fill the entire space when clicked.

Comment: share you try so we can better debug your issue

Comment: @YoungKidWarrior Is [this](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/GRZJjXQ) what you are looking for?

Comment: @fen1x thats it! thank you. if you comment ill accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely positioned children inside parent wrapper is probably *easiest* way to implement your layout for reasons below:

1. `flexbox` is good for 1-dimensional stuff, not so much for 2-dimensional layouts
2. `grid` is not so easy to animate

Snippet below shows the basic implementation:

```js
const animationSpeed = 300;

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('.expandable.expanded')) {
    event.target.classList.remove('expanded');
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.classList.remove('z-top');
    }, animationSpeed);
    return;
  }

  if (event.target.matches('.expandable')) {
    event.target.classList.add('z-top', 'expanded');
    return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.expandable {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: width .3s, height .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.expandable:before {
  content: 'Click to expand';
}

.expandable.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.expandable.expanded:before {
  content: 'Click to shrink';
}

.red {
  background-color: lightpink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.blue {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.purple {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.z-top {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="expandable red"></div>
  <div class="expandable blue"></div>
  <div class="expandable green"></div>
  <div class="expandable purple"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again @fen1x, you should look the sandbox in your answer. Just so people can see an example faster